# How does Android support library work with target SDK level?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I understand that I can use support libraries to add elements that aren't natively available. However, does the newest SDK version (Lollipop, for example) use these support libraries as well, or does it use native elements? E.g. if I run the app on a Lollipop device, will it use native or support elements? I'm asking because, when editing source code (in Android Studio), I'm only editing one version of the file, I can't, for example, chose to create one file for ICS, and other for Lollipop, so how does the system know which elements to use?

Comment: "However, does the target SDK version use these support libraries as well, or does it use native elements?" -- `targetSdkVersion` does not generally affect "native elements". It may affect the resources that Android uses, and it may have other effects as noted in the JavaDocs for `Build.VERSION_CODES`. The Android framework does not use the support libraries. If anything, it's the other way around, particularly for `...Compat` classes (e.g., `NotificationCompat`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, does the newest SDK version (Lollipop, for example) use these support libraries as well, or does it use native elements?

The Android framework does not use the support libraries.

> if I run the app on a Lollipop device, will it use native or support elements?

If I am interpreting what you mean by "native", it uses native element. The Android framework does not use the support libraries.

> I can't, for example, chose to create one file for ICS, and other for Lollipop

You are certainly welcome to detect the running API level and elect to instantiate some level-specific class. You will see this used occasionally in the framework, though it is much more common in the Android support package, particularly for `...Compat` classes.

> so how does the system know which elements to use?

There is only one version of Android per Android device. Hence, there is only one set of framework "elements" for the framework to use.

Some aspects of the look of the widgets are driven by themes, and each Android version ships with support for whatever stock themes existed, going back to `Theme` from API Level 1. If the developer has chosen to use a different theme based upon running API level (e.g., use `Theme.Material` as a base on Android 5.0+ but use `Theme.Holo` as a base on Android 4.0-4.4), that is driven by resource set qualifiers (e.g., `res/values-v21/styles.xml`).

Comment: So, there is a way to use compatibility elements, for older devices, and still use native (non-support) elements for new devices?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović: That depends on what you consider "elements" to be. "Elements" that require you to inherit from certain classes, such as `AppCompatActivity` for `appcompat-v7`, will be difficult to switch. Some "elements" are only in the support libraries, like `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView`. Still others, while you could use native equivalents (`Notification`), you are usually better served using the one from the support libraries (`NotificationCompat`).

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović: But beyond that, you are welcome to use versioned resources and `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` checks to use what you want on different versions. So, if you wanted to use the native `GridLayout`, but use the backport in the support libraries for your Android 2.x devices, you are welcome to do so. Just have a good reason for going through the hassle.

Comment: so, basically, I could use compat library for both old and new versions regardless? Is any of the functionality lost over the native elements? By elements I mean specific parts of the application, like different classes and such.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović: "so, basically, I could use compat library for both old and new versions regardless?" -- usually, yes. "Is any of the functionality lost over the native elements?" -- not usually. If you have concerns over a *specific* element, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you indicate what element it is and inquire about your concerns.